# how to use Array of decimal in 4GL

Tags: stored-procedures, informix, 4gl

My Database is IBM-INFORMIX, I'm writing a Stored Procedure in 4GL.

My Problem is:

Data type of column in which I need to update is `MONEY(16,2)`

Since I'm using 4GL to write my Stored procedure.
I'm trying to use below code to create an array

```
DEFINE li_rate             ARRAY[44] of INTEGER(16,2)
```

Compiling above code gives me error:

```
DEFINE li_rate             ARRAY[44] of INTEGER(16,2)
|_________________________________________________^
|
|      A grammatical error has been found on line 10, character 51.
| The construct is not understandable in its context.
| See error number -4373.
|__________________________________________________^
```

I need a way to create an ARRAY which will be used to hold values to insert in column of data type `MONEY(16,2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried this and it worked.
**DEFINE li_rate   ARRAY[44] of Decimal (16,2)**